# How do I add dynamically widgets to a subtitle? (for ListTile)

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to add Chips to the ListTile subtitle, so that when the listTile is created via a ListView.builder, depending on the user's selection, they can have or see multiple chips in the subtitle.

```
ListView.builder(

      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      itemCount: myShoppingBasketList.length,
      itemBuilder: (ct, shoppingListViewBuilderItemInteger)
      {

       return Card(
            child: ListTile(key: UniqueKey(),
                //dense: true,
                leading: ...,
                title: ...
                subtitle: Wrap(<add chips here)...
                onTap: () 
                {

// Code to add new chips depending on selection


                }

        })
```

So - how could I dynamically += add to a Wrap widget. When I say

```
+=
```

What I'm hoping for is that if a Chip was like a String, then I'd like something like:

```
Wrap(SomeChipContainerWidget = SomeChipContainerWidget+ newChipWidget))
```

Do you see my problem??

So let's say the subTitle was a Text widget, then the String text inside could be:

Text(stringVar += stringVar + newString)

I have tried EVERYTHING - You cannot imagine. I've looked at Expansion Tiles - does't work, Animated, etc..

Any help will be really appreciated. Even sympathy.

Comment: Hello there! Thanks for your input. I cannot see how a row can help here. It maybe OK, I just cannot see. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a List and add a Chip to the List as per your requirement.

Example Code:

```
List<Chip> chips = []; // Global Variable (Add a chip by default)
[...]
ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      itemCount: myShoppingBasketList.length,
      itemBuilder: (ct, shoppingListViewBuilderItemInteger)
      {
       return Card(
            child: ListTile(key: UniqueKey(),
                //dense: true,
                leading: [...],
                title: [...]
                subtitle: Wrap(children: <Widget>[chips])...
                onTap: () 
                {
                   setState((){
                       chips.add(
                        Chip() //Your new chip
                        );
                    });
                }
        })
```

Comment: Thank you Mohit. Well done. THat's the answer. Even if I cannot do it, you are 100% correct here. The question remains as to how I build the onDelete functions within each element in that List Array of Chips.

Comment: Glad that my answer was of some use to you. It is very rare to see someone appreciating the contributors of SO community (both moderators and regular answerers), while the Internet is filled with negative views about being a normal contributor in this community. Challenges do come along the way, but it is only these few lines  of appreciation that keep us motivated above all these adversities. Thank you @Kiro777.

Comment: Oh thank you very much!! Indeed, we can have a list of classes. That's just amazing. My background is C++ and so long ago.. and creating an array, with member elements that were classes was not something I did. I tried to avoid C++ wherever possible and remain procedural. lol.. Now Im paying the price. Why did I not work hard at school!!??

Comment: You still have time:) Btw, it's an array of object and not classes

Comment: I think your message explains to me why I'm having so much difficulty. Thanks Mohit.

Comment: Get back to work if you really want to thank me :) Either ways - Your welcome.